# Show that the two circuits are equivalent mathematically

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra, hadamard, quantum-circuit

This exercise wants me to prove the equivalence of the two circuits using their mathematical representations.

Circuit 1:

[image]

Circuit 2:

[image]

Circuit 1 (`q1` CNOT `q0`) should be represented by $I \otimes P_0 + X \otimes P_1$. Circuit 2 (Hadamard `q0` and `q1`, `q0` CNOT `q1`, Hadamard `q0` and `q1`) should be $(H \otimes H)(P_0 \otimes I + P_1 \otimes X)(H \otimes H)$.

I use the following identities
$$P_0 + P_1 = I = P_{+} + P_{-}$$
$$X = P_{+} - P_{-}$$
$$Z = P_0 - P_1$$
$$P_{+} = HP_0H$$
$$P_{-} = HP_1H$$
where $P_0, P_1, P_{+}, P_{-}$ are $|0\rangle\langle 0|$, $|1\rangle \langle 1|$, $|+\rangle \langle +|$, and $| - \rangle \langle - |$ respectively.

I take circuit 1 and get this:
$$I \otimes P_0 + X \otimes P_1$$
$$= (P_{+} + P_{-}) \otimes P_0 + (P_{+} - P_{-}) \otimes P_1$$
$$= P_{+} \otimes (P_0 + P_1) + P_{-} \otimes (P_0 - P_1)$$
$$= P_{+} \otimes I + P_{-} \otimes Z$$
$$= HP_0H \otimes I + HP_1H \otimes Z$$

Are my circuit representations correct to begin with? If so, should the Z operator be there? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivation is correct and is just missing the final step:

$$
\begin{align}
\dots &= HP_0H \otimes I + HP_1H \otimes Z \\
&= HP_0H \otimes HH + HP_1H \otimes HXH \\
&= (H\otimes H) (P_0 \otimes I) (H\otimes H) + (H\otimes H) (P_1 \otimes X) (H \otimes H) \\
&= (H\otimes H) (P_0 \otimes I + P_1 \otimes X) (H \otimes H)
\end{align}
$$

where we used the identity $HXH=Z$ which is easy to check.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just convert it to matrix representation and show that the two matrix are the same.

**Circuit 1:** This have $q_1$ as the controlled qubit and so it has the matrix representation as unitary matrix $U_1$:
\begin{align}
U_1 = CNOT_{q_1, q_0} &= I \otimes |0\rangle\langle0| + X \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1| = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $|0\rangle\langle 0| = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and $|1\rangle\langle 1| = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $

**Circuit 2:** Here we have $U_2 = H\otimes H \cdot CNOT_{q_0, q_1} \cdot H \otimes H$

where $H = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and hence
$H \otimes H = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $.
Therefore,
$$U_2 =\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  $$

Thus, $U_1 = U_2$.