# Equivalence between quantum circuit: CNOT changes control and target qubit

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, hadamard

It's know that the following two circuits are equal.

[image]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRKVW.png]

In fact, answers for this can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate#Behaviour_in_the_Hadamard_transformed_basis), and on [this website](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15327/show-that-the-two-circuits-are-equivalent-mathematically). However, I am looking for a more formal answer. I'd like to see the answer from the following calculations:

$$|x,y\rangle \to $$
$$(H \otimes H) \to \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j \in \{0,1\}}(-1)^{xi+yj}|i,j\rangle$$
$$ \to (CNOT) \to \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j \in \{0,1\}}(-1)^{xi+yj}|i,i\oplus j\rangle $$
$$ \to (H \otimes H) \to \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i,j,l,k \in \{0,1\}}(-1)^{xi+yj+li+k(i\oplus j)}|l,k\rangle$$

This somehow should be equivalent to
$$= |x \oplus y, y \rangle$$

Comment: you can turn it to operator and do calculation

Comment: Of course I know this. That's exactly what I am trying to avoid.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations are correct. The last steps are:
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac14\sum_{i,j,k,l\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{xi+yj+li+k(i\oplus j)}|l,k\rangle\\
={}&\frac14\sum_{k,l\in\{0,1\}}\left(\sum_{i,j\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{xi+yj+li+ki+kj}\right)|l,k\rangle\\
={}&\frac14\sum_{k,l\in\{0,1\}}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{i(x\oplus l\oplus k)}\right)}_{2\text{ if }x\oplus l\oplus k = 0\text{, }0\text{ otherwise}}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{j\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{j(y\oplus k)}\right)}_{2\text{ if }y\oplus k = 0\text{, }0\text{ otherwise}}|l,k\rangle
\end{align*}$$
Thus, the only term in this sum which is non-zero is the one such that $l=x\oplus k$ and $k=y$, with "amplitude" $4$. All in all, the final state is $|x\oplus y,y\rangle$.