# Show that conjugating $\text{CNOT}$ by $H\otimes H$ exchanges control and target qubits

Tags: quantum-gate, hadamard

I have gotten so far to show that

$$(H⊗H)\text{CNOT}(H⊗H) = (H⊗I)CZ(H⊗I)\,.$$

How do I proceed from here in first proving the identity and then using the identity to show that on the dual basis, when $\text{CNOT}$ is applied target and control are swapped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalence between quantum circuit: CNOT changes control and target qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27165/equivalence-between-quantum-circuit-cnot-changes-control-and-target-qubit)

Comment: I am trying to show in the operator format

Comment: What do you mean by *"show that on the dual basis"*? I am not familiar with this terminology.

Comment: it just means |+> and |-> state for the qubits

Answer (score 5):

The key observation is that the CZ gate, whose action on the computational basis is
$$
\begin{align}
|00\rangle&\mapsto|00\rangle\\
|01\rangle&\mapsto|01\rangle\\
|10\rangle&\mapsto|10\rangle\\
|11\rangle&\mapsto-|11\rangle\\
\end{align}\tag1
$$
is symmetric under the exchange of qubits. In other words,
$$
C_1Z_2=C_2Z_1\tag2
$$
where $C_iU_j$ denotes the controlled-$U$ gate with qubit $i$ as the control and qubit $j$ as the target.  Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
(H\otimes H)\circ C_1X_2\circ(H\otimes H)&=(H\otimes I)\circ C_1Z_2\circ(H\otimes I)\tag3\\
&=(H\otimes I)\circ C_2Z_1\circ(H\otimes I)\tag4\\
&=C_2X_1\tag5
\end{align}
$$
where we first used $HXH=Z$, then $(2)$ and then $HZH=X$ again. $\square$